# Python import subpackage from package outside parent directory

Tags: python, python-import

I have the following folder structure:

```
main_dir

  - api
    - api.py
    - __init__.py

  - service
    - service.py
    - __init__.py

  - yolov5
    - __init__.py
    - models
      - exp.py
      - comm.py
      - __init__.py
 
    - utils
      - downloads.py
      - __init__.py

  - __init__.py

The files contain the following imports:

api.py
from service import detect (detect is a custom class I created in service.py)

service.py
from yolov5.models.exp import attempt_load

exp.py
from models.comm import conv
from utils.downloads import attempt_download

From main_dir I run: python -m api.api
```

When I run the above command, I get:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models' from exp.py.

From what I understand, the yolov5 package is being imported properly but the subpackage models and utils cannot be imported or cannot be referenced from exp.py

The issue is resolved when I change the import statements in exp.py from:

```
from models.comm import conv 
from utils.downloads import attempt_download
```

to

```
from yolov5.models.comm import conv
from yolov5.utils.downloads import attempt_download
```

But I don't want to do that as I'll have to change multiple import statements in different files.
How can I import the subpackage properly? Also, should the python run command be changed or run from a different directory?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use relative imports. All of your code belongs to a single giant package named `main_dir`. As such, you can refer to other modules with that package.

```
# api.py
from ..service import detect (detect is a custom class I created in service.py)

# service.py
from ..yolov5.models.exp import attempt_load

# exp.py
from .comm import conv
from ..utils.downloads import attempt_download
```

A module name with a leading `.` refers to a module in the current package (i.e., the package containing the module being defined). A module name with a leading `..` refers to a module in the package containing the current package, and so on up the line.

I suspect your first two worked unaltered because you have added `main_dir` to your module search path, so `service` and `yolov` are seen as top-level packages. `comm`, however, is in `yolov5.models`, which is *not* a top-level package. Since `exp` and `comm` are both defined in the same package, you need only a single leading `.` to refer to `comm`, not `..` as in the other two examples. Similarly, in `exp.py` the leading `..` refers to `yolov5`, which contains a `utils` module.